# How to fetch values from if else condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am trying to get a code using if else condition.I wish to take values from if else condition .

Currently if condition works, not working for else condition.

```
mname=input("Enter  name: ")
    m=[]

        if mname=="CS1TFD22" or "cs1tfd22":
            mcode='CS122S003'
            if l1l2=="NULL":
                icode = 'CS122S003d13_mh_'
            elif l1l2!="NULL":
                icode = 'CS122S003d13_L1_mh_'

        else:
            for i in mname:
                m.append(i)

            mcode = 'CS1'+m[5]+m[6]+'S003'
            if l1l2=="NULL":
                icode='CS1'+m[5]+m[6]+'S003d113_mh_'
            elif l1l2 != "NULL":
                icode = CS1'+m[5]+m[6]+'S003d13_L1_mh_'

        print(mcode,icode)
```

Output I get is always mcode='CS122S003' and icode='CS122S003d13_L1_mh_', if mname is not 'CS1TFD22'. For example if I enter mname as CS1TFD23 , then icode should be 'CS123S003' and icode should be 'CS123S003d13_mh'

How to work for else condition also?

Comment: This is wrong for sure `if mname=="CS1TFD22" or "cs1tfd22":`, should be `if mname in ("CS1TFD22" ,"cs1tfd22"):`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value)

Comment: What is the code supposed to do? Please include that explanation in your code too!

Comment: Correct your first if statement like this `if mname=="CS1TFD22" or mname=="cs1tfd22":`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some errors in your code

1. You check for two or conditions not by `if mname=="CS1TFD22" or "cs1tfd22":`, but by `if mname=="CS1TFD22" or mname=="cs1tfd22":`, also you can simplify this by doing `if mname.lower()=="cs1tfd22":` .
2. You don't need the extra `elif` in `if l1l2=="NULL":`, just `else` would do .
3. You missed a single quote in `icode = CS1'+m[5]+m[6]+'S003d13_L1_mh_'`
4. You have not defined `li2` anywhere, not sure where you are taking it from, so I am taking it as input in my code

The code with all these issues might look like so

```
mname=input("Enter name: ")
l1l2=input("Enter l1l2")
m=[]

#Convert mname to lower case and then compare
if mname.lower() == 'cs1tfd22':
    mcode='CS122S003'

    #If-else case 1
    if l1l2=="NULL":
        icode = 'CS122S003d13_mh_'
    else:
        icode = 'CS122S003d13_L1_mh_'

else:
    for i in mname:
        m.append(i)
    mcode = 'CS1'+m[5]+m[6]+'S003'

    # If-else case 1
    if l1l2=="NULL":
        icode='CS1'+m[5]+m[6]+'S003d113_mh_'
    else:
        icode = 'CS1'+m[5]+m[6]+'S003d13_L1_mh_'

print(mcode,icode)
```

Some outputs from your code will be.

```
Enter name: cs1tfd22
Enter l1l2:  NULL
CS122S003 CS122S003d13_mh_

Enter name: abcdefgh
Enter l1l2:  NULL
CS1fgS003 CS1fgS003d113_mh_

Enter name: xyzabcd
Enter l1l2:  HELLO
CS1cdS003 CS1cdS003d13_L1_mh_
```

Comment: ` also you can simplify this by doing if mname.lower()=="CS1TFD22":` this is wrong, should be `mname.upper()`

Comment: Damn! I put it correctly in the code but incorrectly in the example! I corrected them at both places! thanks @Netwave Please take a look again and if it looks good, please consider upvoting

Comment: its ok now, gj :)

Comment: What's gj! I don't know this!

Comment: Aah damn! Still learning the ropes of SO so any feedback is always appreciated @Netwave Especially from a high rep user like you :)

Comment: Not really high, I'm quite far away from the real beasts here. I'm learning my way too ;)

Comment: Well 3 times then mine too, so you are a beast for me as well lol ;)

Comment: use casefold() instead

Comment: Well both lower and casefold would work in a similar fashion in this scenario , so either one can be used

Answer (score 2):

Your if statement is always evaluating true, as you are evaluating the logical true/false of a string. You should use

```
if mname=="CS1TFD22" or mname=="cs1tfd22":
```

or

```
if mname in ("CS1TFD22","cs1tfd22"):
```

Comment: Your never which character would be Upper or Lower Case. So its better to use casefold()

Comment: I actually didn't even notice that they were the same string in a different case! In that case yes, should definitely use casefold()

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
if mname=="CS1TFD22" or "cs1tfd22":
```

use

```
 if mname=="CS1TFD22" or mname=="cs1tfd22":
```

Comment: or you can use casefold() also

Comment: this is correct.  "cs1tfd22" allways evaluates to True, so the else condition is never hit

Answer (score 0):

- You should define l1l2 variable.
- Use else instead elif.
- Don't forget ' mark before CS1 at the last line.

  ```
  mname=input("Enter  name: ")
  m=[]
  l1l2=input("Enter  l1l2: ")

  if mname=="CS1TFD22" or "cs1tfd22":
      mcode='CS122S003'
      if l1l2=="NULL":
          icode = 'CS122S003d13_mh_'
      else:
          icode = 'CS122S003d13_L1_mh_'
  else:
      for i in mname:
          m.append(i)

      mcode = 'CS1'+m[5]+m[6]+'S003'
      if l1l2=="NULL":
          icode='CS1'+m[5]+m[6]+'S003d113_mh_'
      else:
          icode = 'CS1'+m[5]+m[6]+'S003d13_L1_mh_'

  print(mcode,icode)
  ```